# not using var partition in a linux web server installation

Tags: linux, webserver, root, var, partition

I know that `var` partition is used to store variable data, administrative and log data. I believe that if i don't create a var partition, the data in the `var` directory will belong to `root` partition.

So if i use a `root (/)` partition with a high size (70% for exemple), did i really need a `/var` partition?

The spécifications of our web server :

```
Os : Linux Centos 6.5 64bit.
Ram : 32 G.
Disk : 830 G.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primarily for safety reasons: If a partition is corrupted, the rest of the system can still be accessible. It may just be enough to restore a backup of the corrupt partition to fix the problem. But also to separate partitions that might be submerged files (eg / var to a mail server that is attacked by a mass mailing ...), the rest of the system would be still operational.

Other partitions separate from the root "/" allows for corruption of another partition, can always boot Linux to fix the system ...
You want to actually be able to boot in "Single user mode" to restore your station or server ... This requires an "intact" root.